# Access Database Search and Display

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2012, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create an app in C# that searches an Access Database after the user has typed in the item and then displays the results.  For example.  Person types in "COKE" it then comes back with aisle and bay number.  I have created the DB and linked it to Visual Studio already.  I just need to know the code that goes in the "Search" button. Thanks.

Comment: please provide the relevant code that you have so far.

Comment: This is not a code service site. Try searching Google for some examples, and then if you have code-specific questions that you need help with, then go ahead and ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll need to create your input capture element.  Not sure if you're using winforms or websites but you would create a text box to take in the input.

You would then need to connect to your database, using something like [SQLCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx).  You'd also need to pass in the input from the search box into your SQL through a parameterized query.

Your SQL query would look something like:

```
select aisle, baynumber from table where column = @searchQuery
```

You would then need to process your resultset. You can use .NET controls such as repeaters or datagrids.